# Python BeautifulSoup4 - Scrape Section/Table Header and Values from Multiple Sections/Tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape links with contextual information from the following page: https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/wiki/discussion_archive/2018. I'm able to get the links just fine using BS4 using Python, but having year, season, titles, and episodes associated to the links is ideal. The desired output would look like this:

[image]

I've started with the code below, but don't know how to loop through the code to capture things in sections for each season/title:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

link = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/wiki/discussion_archive/2018'

request_2018 = session.get(link, headers={'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(request_2018.content, 'lxml')

data_table = soup.find('div', class_='md wiki')
```

Is this something that's doable with BS4? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
criteria = {'class':'md wiki'} # so it can reuse later
data_soup = soup.find('div', criteria)
titles = data_soup.find_all('strong')
tables = data_soup.find_all('table')
```

---

Try following:

```
titles = soup.find('div', {'class':'md wiki'}).find_all('strong')
data_tables = soup.find('div', {'class':'md wiki'}).find_all('table')
```

Better put the second argument of `find` into a dict and `find_all` will return all elements which match your search.

Comment: *Better put the second argument of find into a dict* - why?

Comment: It is doable with ``soup.find('div', class_='md wiki')``. But if you put it in a dictionary, it's good for you to do a more precise ``find`` later on. And more important is that you can init the dict as a variable and pass it in different ``find()`` to make the code more reusable:)

Comment: Good enough. I think you should add it in the answer to support your statement.

Comment: Yup, the answer above is updated. I init a variable to store ``soup.find('div', criteria)`` as well to avoid redundant code. Please have I look:)